# BindingSource is suspended when underlying Collection's Count == 0

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, binding

I have encountered a strange behavior of BindingSource. First I set it's DataSource in designer to a type that will be used by UI for binding, but when I then retrieve the data, then I set the DataSource to a Collection of this type. Everything works fine when the Collection actually stores some objects. Problems begin, when it's empty (not null, just empty). The BindingSource becomes suspended, and even adding something to the Collection doesn't change it, ResumeBinding has no effect too. In this state it's completely useless.

I found a workaround which is simply setting the DataSource to null and then to the same Collection, but this time with added elements (without the setting to null it doesn't work). Can someone explain this to me? Why BindingSource behaves this way? And, of course, is there an elegant way to solve this? I don't like the solution that I found.

Comment: What is the underlying data-source you are using at runtime? this matters...

Comment: It's a Collection<>, I've written it in my post. And the type that it holds is my class, a part of the data model.

Comment: no, you wrote Collection; and Collection != `Collection<T>`. I did not want to make any assumption there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection<T>` doesn't support list notifications, so it has no way of telling the UI to update or do anything useful. Changing to `BindingList<T>` instead of `Collection<T>` should solve this.

Comment: But everything works just fine when the Collection<T> has some objects. The problem is only present, when the bound Collection started with 0 elements. Then the BindingSource.IsBindingSuspended is true and even ResumeBinding() does not change it.
And I cannot use BindingList<T>, it's not my private project and the policy is to use Collection<T> (works for us).

Comment: @CodeMonkey - does your object have an accessible public parameterless constructor? if not, what can it do? it can't add, it has nothing to show, and it has no way of *knowing* when anything is added... what can it usefully do?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by adding the new item, using this code:

```
myBindingsurce.Add(myObject);
```

Instead of

```
myCollectoin.Add(myObject);
```

I had the same problem, when the data source (I have used a List class) is empty. IsBindingSuspended is set to true...

Hope this helps you.